# Unable to edit/add product attribute in admin in magento 2.4.1

Tags: product-attribute, magento2.4

[image]

Kindly help if anybody have any idea

Comment: Add more details

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing and where you need help, your question should be more detailed for everyone to help you.

Comment: Hi, thankyou but I got the solution some modules were disabled So I was getting error at product attribute section in admin

Answer (score 2):

Hi when facing this issue [2021-05-06 08:59:00] main.CRITICAL: Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data::getAttributeHiddenFields() in */vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/product/attribute/js.phtml:216
Stack trace:

The fix is here
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/30277